# Fuelux TypeError: b is undefined

Tags: javascript, fuelux

I am trying using fuelux 2.6 but I am getting 
    TypeError: b is undefined. 
Unable to solve it. 
If I use simply a web page with bootstrap, jquery and fuelux javascripts I do not get this error, so the error should be on my webpage, but I have tried removing all other js libraries from the page, leaving only jquery, bootstrap and fualux and I still get the error

Comment: How can we help you if you don't show the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The problem is that fuelux javascript

```
<script src="path/to/fuelux.min.js"/>
```

should be placed right after

```
<script src="path/to/bootstrap.min.js"/>
```